# Querying OData API Child of Child returns empty/null values

Tags: odata, sitefinity

I am attempting to query OData where I am expanding the child of a child.

From my understanding the query should look like:

promopages?sf_culture=en&$expand=promopagebanners($expand=promoimage)

In my case the promopages are returned along with their child promopagebanners but the promoimage child of each promopagebanner looks like:

```
"PromoImage": {
        "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "LastModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "PublicationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Title": null,
        "Description": null,
        "DateCreated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Ordinal": 0,
        "UrlName": null,
        "Author": null,
        "Extension": null,
        "MimeType": null,
        "TotalSize": 0,
        "Category": [],
        "Tags": [],
        "Width": 0,
        "Height": 0,
        "AlternativeText": null,
        "FolderId": null,
        "ParentId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "Url": null,
        "ThumbnailUrl": null
      }
```

If I query promopagebanners directly and expand the promoimage the expected result is returned which is the above object sans nulls, 0 etc.